# Local NuGet - Notify on newer package?

Tags: c#, nuget

I am running a local NuGet on our network folder/share.

The official NuGet source notifies me if there is newer release of a package that i'm using, but it's not work locally. I can receive new releases via 'Package Manager Console' and 'Manage NuGet Packages'.

Is it possible to receive update notifcations locally or is there a reason why NuGet is not notifying me locally?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem.

Comment: Check if you have the proper url to NUGET api and/or the nuget api url isnt blocked..

Comment: @BaljeetsinghSucharia At least in my case installing and updating the packages was possible. I'm running TeamCity and it just works.

Comment: cool that its solved - why dont you update answer your  answer with tried solution so that is useful to others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found a way that Nuget notifies me when using a local network folder. The easiest way is probably to use private gallery and a CI Server like [TeamCity](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2013/08/nuget-package-restore-with-teamcity/)